# Can there be intention without an intender?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, descartes, intentionality

Many refutations of Descartes cogito go along the line of:

All Descartes really proved is that thinking is happening, but there can be thinking without there being a thinker to do the thinking. Just as there can be raining without a "rainer", or snowing without a "snower", there is nothing illogical about thinking occurring without a thinker. The move from "there is thinking" to "I think" is not a necessary one.

But I am wondering if the same can be said of intentionality?

Unlike thinking, intending is a directed relationship between two entities: Intention doesn't occur without a source and a target of the intention.

It is it possible to substitute thinking with intention, and use that as a neo-Cartesian proof for the existence of self?

Comment: I would suggest that survival is an intention without a target, and with an ambiguous source.

Comment: @jobermark how is it ambiguous ?

Comment: It seems to me to be an intention that can be had with very limited mind.  You fall down the well of my previous problem with 'thinking'.  It is the same question.  Do bacteria 'intend', when they do things in order to survive?  Then are they really not doing them *in order* to survive?  Proposing that seems evasively obtuse.  If their intention to survive does not make them intenders, why does ours?  OTOH, if it does, then do they have 'selves'?  You end up with phenotypes or individual genes having selves, unless you place some weird side condition to clarify what kind of intending you mean.

Comment: After all, from a certain perspective our intention to survive is really just the composite of our selfish genes' intentions to survive.  Who owns the intention?  And the only target would have to be either the process of survival, which is pretty vague, or the same as the source.

Comment: The report of "thinking" is supposed to convey something much more basic than the notion of "I", which requires quite a bit of abstraction and sophistication. When Descartes reduces himself to the base state with his doubt there is no extracting "I" or "thinker" out of that, he just inserts the mature notion of empirical self, with "I am" in it. This is like using the law of cosines to prove the Pythagorean theorem. In this sense "intending" is no better than "thinking", the kinds of distinctions you are making are not available at the point where they could save cogito from circularity.

Comment: @jobermark Maybe evolution, rather than survival, is a closely related but better example of "disembodied intention", intention without an intender.

Comment: @JohnForkosh the hallmark of biological evolution is the removal of teleology from biological explanations. Shall we put it back?

Comment: Maybe it's time to move on from refuting Descartes *cogito*, and begin to discuss other things that Descarte wrote on; its rather like getting stuck on page one of a text...theres that film called groundhog day.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy There's no **conscious** purpose/intention, but there's "purpose" in the same way that, e.g., the "purpose" of a falling object is to reach a state of minimal potential energy. I'd assume there can never be any **conscious** purpose/intention without a conscious intender, but I'm suggesting intention can have an unconscious component, with evolution (and gravity, etc) exhibiting behavior that can be described/characterized in terms of such an unconscious purpose.

Comment: @JohnForkosh, that's poetry.

Comment: @JohnForkosh  I would object that is not the intention of the falling object.  When I fall, I seldom intend to reach the ground, it is generally quite against my will.  Neither evolution, nor response to the gravitational force can really be considered intentions, to me.  Survival is something that clearly requires choices on the part of the animal.  Evolution isn't.  But the phenotype seems to 'choose' genes so that it might survive.

Comment: @jobermark Re evolution and phenotype, there's really no such "thing" (no underlying "genotype") as evolution. E.g., when an animal with bad eyesight stops for a drink and gets eaten by a crocodile, that's not "evolution", that's "lunch". It's only we thinking beings who abstractly collect the overalll effect of lots of such lunches, and call it "evolution". But it clearly doesn't exist, per se. So "it" clearly can't have intention itself. But we thinking beings can likewise associate an abstract/unconscious intention with the "overall effect" we're calling evolution. Ditto falling rocks.

Comment: @JohnForkosh  Then there is no choice when your neurons fire, either.  'We thinking beings' can do and say whatever we want on the subject of intention, but without simply *declaring it so*, you need a real reason to distinguish the choice of the genes that constitute a genotype from the choice of what you had for lunch.  Remember at what a basic level we are meant to be considering this.  What definition of choice or intention can you make that does not already presume the cogito and yet still *really distinguishes* the cases you want separated?

Comment: @jobermark Okay, perhaps I'm interpreting (or maybe defining) "intention" more broadly than intended. For (another) example, if you roll a pair of dice, seven's the most likely outcome, and I'd broadly say that the physical/mathematical situation exhibits/is-chracterized-by an "unconscious intention" towards seven. Analogous to your conscious intention (that you used as an example in preceding comment) towards survival. In both cases, the intention is more often than not carried out, but not always. Moreover, the dice have non-deterministic "choice", in an again-unconscious way, by statistics.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you get to your neo-Cartesian proof of self from the fact that intention requires an intender, without begging the question. The word intention is used in our language to describe that to which we ascribe some property of self or will, but that it is used as a term doesn't prove it's existence. Time-travelling, needs a time-traveller to do it, but that does not prove time-travelling exists.

Decartes's conclusion differs. He is saying "this thing I'm doing now, I will call thinking. It therefore requires a thinker, because something has to be doing the action by which the thing requires a definition"

This would not be true of intention, because intention is not the same action as considering the act of intending.

Answer (score 1):

No, there can not be intentionality without an intentionalistic agent, nor can there be intending without an intender.

Anthropomorphizing rain and snow does not support the notion that *because there can be snowing without a "snower", then there can be thinking without a thinker.* The cause of snow and rain do not involve volition; these phenomena are the result of "[brute](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3326788?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)" and non-intentionalistic cause. The description of snow having a "snower" is [metaphorical](http://people.exeter.ac.uk/sp344/intetnt%20and%20its%20placeinnature%20searle.pdf).

Of note, intending is a kind of intentionality, but intentionality is not limited to intent. Reading your question, I am not sure if you are [distinguishing intent and intentionality](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2203638/#s1atitle). Also of note, [Brentano](http://www.univpgri-palembang.ac.id/perpus-fkip/Perpustakaan/Filsafat/Ontologi/Franz%20Brentano-PSYCHOLOGY%20FROM%20AN.pdf) reintroduced the term and in intent German is "absicht", intend is "wollen" and intentional, "intentionale" and intentionality "intentionalität". Such are technical words English inherits from German by way of Latin...

> All Descartes really proved is that thinking is happening, but there can be thinking without there being a thinker to do the thinking.

Is this what DesCartes said, or is this a dualistic inference?

As for a "neo-DesCartesian" proof of self which substitutes intentionality (or intending) for *cogito*, sure why not? Go for it. DesCartes, however, came to the conclusion of "cogito ergo sum" from a method of radical skepticism in which he doubted everything and discovered there was one thing he was unable to doubt: that he was thinking. He was not proving the existence of self, just that there is at the very least one thing which he could not doubt, i.e. his proof is epistemic, not ontological. *Intendo ergo sum* would be an interesting project, however, that you are intending to do something, you could still be deceived (if you deem the argument from hallucination convincing). It may be sufficient that your existence is demonstrated by your intention (or intentionlity) but is it necessary? Also, does thinking removed from a first person subjective ontology have a third-person objective or subjective or first-person objective ontology? Wouldn't these be contrary to the notion of [intentionality](https://www.scribd.com/doc/97933716/3b-Searle-1983-Intentionality)?

If you are intending to also argue DesCartesian dualism, you might also benefit from [this article, particularly section 5](http://ist-socrates.berkeley.edu/~jsearle/DualismRevisited28Aug06.doc).

Answer (score 0):

The difference of opinion in a lot of questions, I find, comes down to our definitions of the words we use. To me it seems intention is something prescribed by a 'thinker' rather than nature. You cannot say the rain intended to fall, only that the laws of nature dictated that it would. Just so, if we take the view of solipsism then no other being has intention.

Determinism would say none of us have intentions, it is only an attempt to preserve our idea of free-will.

It really depends where you draw your definition but I would say that intention is an abstract concept and requires, at least, a thinker for it to be possible. The thinker, however, could merely be explaining what they see by to preserve free-will.

We now have another conundrum though:
If a rain drop could be a thinker and thought "I just got bored of those clouds, I really want to get to the ground now." Is there an intention despite there being no control?

I would say no but that is just my definition of intent. To me there can be no intention or intender without free-will, only a preservation of the concept of free will for a thinker.

Answer (score 0):

There can be thought without a thinker if epiphenomenalism is true, but there still is some underlying *substance* (whatever criticisms you assail against that notion, you'll end up relying on some form of substance nevertheless to analyze thought), so it's clear then that hard determinism and eliminative materialism aren't what you're getting at, but rather there being something happening without there being something underlying it (substance). If this is not so, then what do you mean by 'thought'? Has to be organized somewhere (yes, we should reject the nonspatiotemporal).